# Quiero saber si hay alguna manera de meter varios datos de manera simultanea a una tabla o preguntar cuantas veces desea meter datos?

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

Estoy queriendo reemplazar una hoja de excel donde se ingresa las ventas de 5 cajeros pero no podría crear cada campo para cada cajero porque la tabla tendría 65 campos así que la mejor opción es una tabla para 1 cajero e ingresarlos uno por uno así solo son 16 campos que es un poco mejor pienso, mi duda es si hay manera de si en caso se lleguen a ingresar datos para 3 cajeros por ejemplo si se puede hacer simultáneamente? porque hasta lo poquisimo que llevo seria de preguntar cuantos cajeros y que por un bucle me este haciendo meter los datos para los 3 y luego terminar(si solo así, se pues no termino de saber como seria) les comparto un ejemplo de lo que seria

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Prueba</title>
</head>

<script type="text/javascript">
             function prueba1()
             {
                 var valor = prompt("Ingrese la cantidad de cajeros", "");
 
                 if( valor = " " ) {
                     alert("Porfavor Ingrese un numero:");
                 }else{

                 }
             }
    </script> 

<body onload="prueba1();">

    <form action="sav" method="post">

        <h2>PRUEBA FORMULARIO</h2><br><br>
        <label>Nombre</label>
        <input type="text" name="a1" required><br><br><br>

        <label>N1</label>
        <input type="text" name="a2" required><br><br><br>

        <label>N2</label>
        <input type="text" name="a3" required><br><br><br>

        <button type="submit">Guardar</button>
    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

El guardar

```
<?php
include "conexion/db.php"; 

$a= $_POST['a1'];
$b = $_POST['a2'];
$c = $_POST['a3'];

$clave= $_POST['zz'];

if($wer=0 <= $clave){
   $query="insert into prueba (Nombre, N1, N2) values('$a', '$b', '$c')"; 
   $resul= $cone->query($query); 
   $wer++;


   header('Location: http://'.$server.'/Proyecto/pru');


}else{
    print '<script>'; 
    print 'alert("No fue posible guardar los datos");';
    print '</script>'; 
}

?>
```

Comment: No se si la "pregunta" se puede formular de una manera mas clara

Comment: Se puede generar una tabla y por medio de js con la función append preparar de manera dinámica las filas que necesitas almacenar. Una ves agregues las filas que necesitas envías los datos con el submit del formulario

Comment: @AbrahamChan ahorita voy a investigar como funciona, gracias!